# alternate approach to dot product using conjugate

Tags: inner-products

To determine if two vectors are within 90° of each other we simply look for a positive result from the dot product.

$\vec{p} \cdot \vec{q} = \left | \vec{p} \right |\left | \vec{q} \right |\cos\theta $

On pdf page 4 of [this paper](https://cdn.selinc.com/assets/Literature/Publications/Technical%20Papers/6045_NewDevelopments_Web.pdf), they are using a different approach using conjugation that is supposed to be numerically more efficient. If their result, $T$, is positive then the two vectors are within 90° of each other.

$T = Re[\vec{p}*\vec{q^*}]$

**Example**: $\vec{p}=+j25$, $\vec{q}=-j40$

Dot product approach:  $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{q} = (25)(40)\cos180°=-1,000$

Paper approach: $T = Re[(+j25)(+j40)]=-1,000$

So, both approaches produce the exact same result and show the vectors are not within 90° of each other.

**My question**:  What is the derivation for the "paper approach" equation?  I can't find anything describing its derivation and would like to understand how it was arrived at.

thanks,
russ

Comment: I would however be a bit skeptical about the claim that the complex number approach is faster as it ends up requiring 4 products and 2 sums as opposed to 2 products and one sun. It may be that for their specific implementation  that is faster but without an actual benchmark I would be cautious of changing how you compute dot products everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two vectors:
$\vec{x} = (a, b)$ and $\vec{y}=(c,d)$  now imagine for a second that those pairs of numbers represent complex numbers $\hat{x} = a + ib$ and $\hat{y} = c + id$.

Then $\hat{x} \hat{y}^*=(ac + bd) + i (bc - ad)$ taking the real part of that is just $ac + bd$.

On the other hand the dot product $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=ac+bd$ so the two produce the same result.